# Tensorflow error while importing in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I have Python 2.7 on MacOS.

I have built Tensorflow from the source using bazel as below:

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I am getting the below error while I am trying to import the Tensorflow package.

import tensorflow as tf

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal
```

Comment: Did you do every step? After bazel build you need to run the script it generates and then install the resulting package using pip

Comment: I had missed the $ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.1.0-py2-none-any.whl    Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing using pip it worked.

```
$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.1.0-py2-none-any.whl
```